# Getting query parameters from authentication URL in iOS - swift and reactjs

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, authentication

I am trying to figure out how I can get the query parameters for my authentication. They are in the URL and work on android, but having difficulty on iOS.

This is the code i use on Android once a user returns to the app.

```
 App.addListener("appUrlOpen", (data) => {
    console.log("Received appUrlOpen event:", data);
    const url = new URL(data.url);
    const token = url.searchParams.get("access_token");
    const refresh = url.searchParams.get("refresh_token");
    setAccessToken(token);
    setRefreshToken(refresh);
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify("logged in"));
  });
```

Also tried to use swift to save the access and refresh token and then retrieve it in the main app.js. But this also does not seem to be working.

The swift code is printing both the access and refresh token so the data is coming through. It just does not seem to be communicating with the main app.js file.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if url.scheme == "my-scheme-app" {
        if let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false),
           let queryItems = components.queryItems {
            var accessToken: String?
            var refreshToken: String?

            for queryItem in queryItems {
                if queryItem.name == "access_token" {
                    accessToken = queryItem.value
                } else if queryItem.name == "refresh_token" {
                    refreshToken = queryItem.value
                }
            }

            if let accessToken = accessToken, let refreshToken = refreshToken {
                // Handle tokens and update state here
                print("Access Token: \(accessToken)")
                print("Refresh Token: \(refreshToken)")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: "accessToken")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(refreshToken, forKey: "refreshToken")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TokensSaved"), object: nil)

                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    function handleTokensSaved(event) {
      const { accessToken, refreshToken } = event.detail;
      console.log("Access Token:", accessToken);
      console.log("Refresh Token:", refreshToken);
      setAccessToken(accessToken);
      setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
      localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", refreshToken);
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify("logged in"));
    }

    window.addEventListener("TokensSaved", handleTokensSaved);

    // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("TokensSaved", handleTokensSaved);
    };
  }, []);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.